# postgresql installs an extension, but does not expose the functions in it

Tags: postgresql, toolkit, timescaledb

I am using PostgreSQL 14. I have finally managed to build the timescaledb-toolkit for it (based on the alpine docker image) and now I get the control file, the library, everything. So, I execute

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb_toolkit;
```

and there is no error, but the moment I try to use *any* function defined on the extension I get

```sql
db=# SELECT time_bucket('5m'::interval, time) AS five_min, delta(counter_agg(time, energy_t1_in)) AS net_in FROM electricity GROUP BY five_min;
ERROR:  function counter_agg(timestamp without time zone, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: ...e_bucket('5m'::interval, time) AS five_min, delta(counter_ag...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Following [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/255437) I can see that no methods are listed for the extension, which makes me think that somehow the extension is installed but not really "registered" (?). How can I fix this?

Comment: Connect with `psql` and verify with `\dx+ timescaledb_toolkit`.

Comment: Is this a `search_path` issue?  Where the extension installed it's functions in a schema that is not currently in your `search_path`. On `psql` do `\dn` for the schemas and `show search_path` for the current path. Add as update to your question.

Comment: Did this issue get resolved? We likewise wish to run the Toolkit on the Alpine-based Docker image, but have not even gotten as far as you.

Comment: @ArturoAguilar Nope, I did not get through. I switched to the HA docker container and did not give it any more thought :-/